# Check if an iOS project is using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods, github-api

Is there a way to figure out if an iOS repository is using cocoapods or not?

At my first thought I was planning to use github api and check if the Podfile exists. But there could be repositories which has podfile but are not actually using it.

I am working on a ruby script in which I need to figure out if the iOS repo's is using cocoapods.

Comment: What does this ruby script _do_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your best bet would be to do what you're saying and check if there is a `Podfile`. I think the bigger problem with this approach would be you'd have to check in nested directories too. If you wanted to make this way more complicated than it's worth you could use the [`xcodeproj`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) gem and look around the project's linked files for the `Pods.xcconfig`.